# When should I use distinct in a query?

Tags: sql, distinct

This is a general question:
Does anyone have a tip as to how i can know when i should use distinct in my queries ? I am struggling at understanding when to use it exactly. I tend to use it when I don't need it and not when I do.

thank you all very much.

Comment: If I had an Employee table containing a columns for the employee's name and address (Street, City, State/Provence, Country) do you know the difference between `SELECT Country from Employee` and `SELECT DISTINCT Country from Employee`? What if I wanted to know how many different (distinct) countries my employees represent?

Comment: the first query would count the same country multiple times ?

Comment: Yes. It would select (i.e. display) the Country column from *every* row. The second query would not show duplicates and therefore if I had 100 employees from 7 different countries, only 7 rows would be shown. `select count(distinct Country) from Employee` would  return 7.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, there is little reason to use `select distinct` -- although it is sometime convenient short-hand.

If it can be avoided, avoid it!  SQL incurs overhead for removing duplicates, even if there are no duplicates.  So, `select distinct` is slower than `select`.

Often `select distinct` is more appropriately written using `group by` -- because often you want *some* column to be aggregated (such as the maximum date/time).

That said, it can be convenient shorthand, so it should not be avoided altogether, just used rarely.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general rule as to when to use DISTINCT, it is based on your requirement i.e. when you have two same values in one column but you only require one value so you will use distinct.

Suppose you have a list of banks and branches in a city. But you need to know how many unique banks are operating in the city then you will write

```
select distinct bank_name from city;
```

Comment: The table's name is `city` and it describes banks and branches? Not a great example. What if you had a bank_table that described various banks and its branches with its addresses? Then `select distinct bank_name from bank_table where city = 'Oshkosh'`

Answer (score 0):

I use distinct when I want to ensure rows are not duplicated in a query that could have duplicate records for the field combination I am selecting. Generally, this would be when selecting a set of columns that do not include a primary/unique key and are not guaranteed to be unique when the selected fields are taken together.

For example, if I was selecting customers that had purchased this year to send a letter to, and customers can have more than one order in a single year and I want to ensure that I send only one letter per person and address, I would use Distinct to ensure that I get one occurrence of each unique customer name / address combination.

```
--could return multiple records for repeat customers if Distinct was not present
Select Distinct BillingName, BillingAddress 
from Orders 
where OrderDate > '2019-08-01'
```